# Why does mypy consider this augmented assignment an error?

Tags: python, mypy

I have the following code in file test.py:

```
a = 3.5
a = 4
a = 0.5 * a

b = 3.5
b = 4
b *= 0.5
```

Console output:

```
File test.py
    Line 7: Unsupported operand types for * ("int" and "float")
```

Mypy version used: 0.4.4

Why is line 3 right and line 7 wrong?

Later edit:

This behaviour has now been classified as a bug in mypy.

https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2098

So it's to be expected that both statement sequences will be acceptable to mypy in the future.

Comment: as the error message reads, you cannot multiply floats and integers together. what python version does the Mypy 0.4.4 use ?

Comment: I am using 3.5. And although the run time type for b is int after b = 4, the static type should still be float, as is the case with a in the first three lines, that do not give this error.

Comment: Line 3 is correct because it creates a new integer object (which then is assigned to `a`) while line 7 tries to modify `b` in-place which cannot be done since it is an integer. In other words `a *= b` **is not** the same as `a = a * b`.

Comment: Never used mypy so pure guess : maybe `b *=` is prohibited because it change b type in a way that seems less explicit than `a = 0.5 * a`.

Comment: @freakish: Isn't that an implementation matter, something the typechecker shouldn't bother about? I've checked and the result is a float. To be clear, the interpreter thinks its fine and makes b equal to 2.0, which is a float. Only the typechecker doesn't seem to understand that.

Comment: Your title is not useful.  You mention mypy, but don't show its part in the code you have shown

Comment: @polku: You may very well be right. Still I expected the type checker to see through this in this trivial case.

Comment: Seems simple: Static typing in mypy must mean that in-place operations like `*=` cannot change the type of the operand.

Comment: Mypy is a statical checker. I've used it to check my code. It's not something you import or anything like that.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge For numbers both operators work the same since they are immutable anyway. But for other types they don't work the same (e.g. lists). So it is not an implementation detail, generally the behaviour is different. I suspect that this was done for consitency.

Comment: @freakish. Thanks, that may be the case. Unfortunately the result is rather counterintuitive in this case.

Comment: @martineau: The static type of the operand was still float, isn't it?

Comment: `b` is set to an integer in line 6. The result of multiplying it by `0.5` is a float, so to perform the augmented assignment, it would have to change the type of `b` into something different from what it currently is.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge I'm guessing that mypy doesn't mind the former as `a = 0.5 * a` is effectively take float 0.5 and multiple by a and bind the result to `a` which is different than `b *= 0.5` which is mutate a known int by multiplying by a float which will attempt to directly change the known type of `b`. Don't forget that `=` is name binding and not assignment... that's why mypy isn't moaning at your first two lines: `a = 3.5; a = 4`...

Comment: @martineau: I agree that this is what happens to the dynamic type, the runtime type so to say. But from the docs of mypy I gather that the static type of a variable is determined the first time that it is assigned to. So it is quite normal in mypy that the dynamic type, given by the type operator is e.g. int, while the static type, inferred by mypy is float.

Comment: @Jacques: Sounds like a bug in mypy or its documentation (or your understanding of it ;-). Perhaps the "dynamic" type of `b` is being changed by line 6 to `int`.

Comment: @martineau: The weird thing is that in that case I would also expect line 2 to change the static type of a to int and line 3 should fail as well. Anyhow, I've filed an issue for this on mypy's github account...